# Should Rust give an error with this one liner to concatenate a new string to another using push_str()?

Tags: string, rust, concatenation

I want to concatenate a String.
In my opinion the following code should give some sort of a panic or compiler error.

```
let mut s = String::from("abc").push_str("x");
println!("{:?}", s); // Prints ()
```

But this code works:

```
let mut s = String::from("abc");
s.push_str("x");  
println!("{:?}", s); // Prints "abcx"
```

Comment: There's a question lacking in your question. I know what you want to achieve, but please try to ask a question which we should answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In my opinion the following code should give some sort of a panic or compiler error.

Why should it? This code is perfectly legal.

`s` is now a unit value `()` and because you are using `{:?}` which is the `Debug` output it prints `()`.

This is a good time to introduce clippy to you. With `cargo clippy` you receive the following warning:

```
warning: this let-binding has unit value
 --> src/main.rs:2:5
  |
2 |     let mut s = String::from("abc").push_str("x");
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: omit the `let` binding: `String::from("abc").push_str("x");`
  |
  = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#let_unit_value
  = note: `#[warn(clippy::let_unit_value)]` on by default
```

which indicates that something is fishy in your code.

Answer (score 5):

[`push_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.push_str) doesn't return the input string; it has no return value. Methods with no return value implicitly return `()`.

```
pub fn push_str(&mut self, string: &str)
```

Comment: Understood. Maybe my more precise question is why doesn't String::from("abc") create a temporary heap reference that push_str()  can then concatenate with.

Comment: It does. That's why the code compiles. The temporary string is dropped at the end of the `let` statement, though, because `push_str` doesn't return it.